# Fatal error: class not found using pear in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, pear

I'm trying to send an email using form data. I'm adapting the method described at http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html which uses the PEAR library. I'm testing my site locally via XAMPP.

Here's the code from the top of my page:

```
<?php 
// Pear library includes
include_once('Mail/mail.php');
include_once('Mail/mime.php');
```

Testing the page produces the following:

Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail\mail.php on line 51

Here's line 51 from mail.php (I haven't altered the file from the default XAMPP installation):

```
class Mail_mail extends Mail {
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you installed Pear Mail? Is there a Mail class in C:\xampp\php\PEAR

Comment: C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail contains mail.php and mime.php

Comment: I haven't installed anything other than XAMPP, I was under the impression it all came as a package

Comment: convert to a `require_once()` and see if either package is actually being included or not.

Comment: @Marc B - Converting to require_once() throws the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
include_once('Mail/mail.php');
```

to

```
include_once('Mail.php');
```

Comment: Its the way Pears namespacing and autoloading works. Mail_Mime will be in Mail/mime.php, as Mail has no other namespace parts its just in the root Pear folder. Ie replace the _ with a slash to get the folder path.